# Creating a Paper on LaTeX and importing R Packages onto LaTeX

Tags: r, error-handling, package, latex, r-markdown

I am a novice with LaTeX and R.  I am creating a report on LaTeX (under Overleaf) and want to include some R code.  I handled this fine, but when I want to include an R package, I am producing an error.  Here is what I type out as an example:

```
<<>>=
install.packages("rmarkdown")
install.packages("AdequacyModel")
library(AdequacyModel)
@
```

And here is the respective error:

```
Error:  <text>:2:18:  unexpected input## 1:  install.packages(’rmarkdown’)
2:  install.packages(<e2>##
```

Could somebody please explain to me (as if I am at a fourth grade level) why this occurs and a solution to this problem?

Comment: You need a different "engine", in essence you need R to drive this.  Overleaf, for all I know, does not offer this.  Hence the error.

Comment: Or conversely, you need a different tool.  You could try [RStudio Cloud](https://rstudio.cloud).  I keep forgetting if the latex environment is full featured or not but as I recall you install missing pieces.  Maybe an alternative...

Comment: On Overleaf you don't need to install Rmarkdown to knit documents (for example, see: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/sample-rtex-document/phftyfcvjywp) and I believe you can use functions from the AdequacyModel package by including `library(AdequacyModel)` without having `install.packages("AdequacyModel")` - in the linked example the author loads xtables and ggplot without installing them beforehand

Comment: Hi Dirk, thank you for the recommendation for RStudio Cloud.  Also, what do you mean by "..you need R to drive this."?  I am confused.
Hi jared_mamrot, thank you for the recommendation.  I omitted "install.packages("rmarkdown")" and "install.packages("AdequacyModel") and then kept "library(AdequacyModel)".  However, it seems like LaTeX cannot retrieve this type of package from the library.  Do you know if LaTeX will not read some packages (like this one) from R?  If so, why?